# Multiple prompts with nsIPromptService

Tags: javascript, firefox, web, xul, prompt

Can we show multiple prompt windows with Firefox Addon SDK?

I were looking into [nsIPromptService](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIPromptService). The most similar function to what I want is `promptUsernameAndPassword()` and I want to ask the user a prompt and select dialog in the same box.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Either use `nsIPromptService` yourself via the [`Chrome Authority`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Chrome_Authority) if it suits your needs.
- or create a [`panel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel), which is, of course, not a real dialog.
- or implement your own XUL dialog, (which isn't exactly easy).